# Effective degrees of freedom for spline term in glmmTMB

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, mgcv, glmmtmb

I have fitted a model in glmmTMB that includes an spline function for age using the bs function from the splines package (version 3.6.2) in R. The syntax in glmmTMB looks like this:
glmmTMB(litter_size ~ bs(maternal_age, 3) +  prey_abundance + (1|motherID),
data = ourdata, family=poisson)

One of my colleagues suggested that I should provide the *effective degrees of freedom* (EDF) for the spline term when reporting the results. Is there a method to get the EDF for this term from the glmmTMB model object?

I know I can get the EDF by using the mgcv package but in this case, I prefer to use glmmTMB if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spline you included in the model isn't penalised so its EDF is 3 because that's what you set it to.

To confirm, run `with(ourdata, ncol(bs(maternal_age, 3)))` and check the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll switch to the mgcv package for the modelling to get penalized splines. The [example](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2021/02/02/random-effects-in-gams/) you have made on random effects in mgcv has been really helpful in this respect.